# Javascript: Firefox ignores dateStyle and timeStyle options in both Date.toLocaleString and Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeStyle: "long", dateStyle: "long"}).format());
```

Chrome says: "February 13, 2020 at 7:33:18 PM EST".

Firefox says: "2/13/2020"

Firefox also ignores dateStyle and timeStyle when using `toLocaleString`.

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeStyle: "short", dateStyle: "short"}));
console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeStyle: "medium", dateStyle: "medium"}));
console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeStyle: "long", dateStyle: "long"}));
```

All of these lines give the same result in Firefox: "2/13/2020, 8:04:11 PM". Chrome correctly gives different values.

What's going on? How do I get a locale-correct date string in Firefox?

Edit: Apparently Firefox doesn't support these properties.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat#Browser_compatibility

Comment: First time ever it wasn't my fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` options are still at [proposal state](https://tc39.es/proposal-intl-datetime-style/) (stage 3).

Browsers are not forced to implement it yet, and may very well want to wait for the specs to stabilize before implementing this.

For the time being, you can still use the default options to get a less natural but still localized result:

```js
const supports = testDateTimeStyleSupport();

const opts = supports ? { dateStyle: "long", timeStyle: "long" } : {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric"
}

console.log( new Intl.DateTimeFormat( undefined, opts ).format() );

// assumes both are supported or none
function testDateTimeStyleSupport() {
  let support = false;
  const tester = {
    get dateStyle() { support = true; }
  };
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat( undefined, tester );
  return support;
}
```

Comment: Other answers said that Firefox supported both `Intl.DateTimeFormat` and `Date.toLocaleString`. I assumed they meant _completely_ supported.

Comment: There are great chances that at the time these answers were posted, dateStyle and timeStyle were not even a proposal, not even a thought yet. It's written everywhere that dateStyle and timeStyle are "experimental features", and they shouldn't be used yet.

Comment: Ok, I see the flask icon now. I don't understand why they're at the top of the page, above the supported functions. I would think experimental, or not-completely-supported features, would be below the supported ones, or at least someplace other than the top of the document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString