# For JavaScript's toLocaleDateString, are there new standards to replace dateStyle and timeStyle?

Tags: javascript

I had some code that worked well before:

```
(new Date()).toLocaleDateString("en", { dateStyle: "medium", timeStyle: "medium" })
```

in Google Chrome (right now I am using the latest version 87.0.4280.67), and it seemed from March 2020 to Nov 2020, it has stopped working and it'd throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid option : timeStyle
```

and [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) doesn't mention it whatsoever, and I remember the MDN docs was exactly where it was suggesting to use `timeStyle` in the past.  Instead, I see options such as

```
{ weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }
```

How does it work now and are there some pre-defined formats that can be used?

Comment: @Andreas it throws an error.  What do you expect?  Anybody can type that into Chrome and see the error. What kind of "sample" do you want?

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://jsbin.com/basumufovi/edit?js,console). Weirdly it works on Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Firefox ignores dateStyle and timeStyle options in both Date.toLocaleString and Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218476/javascript-firefox-ignores-datestyle-and-timestyle-options-in-both-date-tolocal)

Comment: "*Anybody can type that into Chrome and see the error.*" I'm not getting an error. Moreover, even if I did, then perhaps in another 6 months I'd stop getting the error. Or I get a *different one*. Future visitors will have a hard time seeing if this applies to them.

Comment: Also note that MDN *does* mention *"The locales and options arguments are not supported in all browsers yet."*

Answer (score 5):

This is what I found so far that work well:

Although `toLocaleDateString` still takes a `locale` and `options` as indicated on MDN:

```
dateObj.toLocaleDateString([locales[, options]])
```

it does not work like before.  To be able to use the pre-defined formats such as a `full`, `long`, `medium`, or `short` date or time, the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` is used instead:

The `DateTimeFormat` object is not to be supplied to `toLocaleDateString` for it to work:

```
(new Date()).toLocaleDateString(new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { dateStyle: "medium", timeStyle: "medium" }))   
// => "11/26/2020"
```

This would work:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { dateStyle: "medium", timeStyle: "medium" }).format(new Date())    
// => "Nov 26, 2020, 4:52:55 AM"
```

There are currently two docs and [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) doesn't have the information while [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) does.

Answer (score 2):

As of [MDN toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

> The toLocaleDateString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the date portion of this date.

So I guess the `timeStyle` option is invalid because the method only regards the date portion anyway, thus the option has no effect. For me using `toLocaleString` instead of `toLocaleDateString` works in Google Chrome:

```
(new Date()).toLocaleString("en", { dateStyle: "medium", timeStyle: "medium" })
```